# Get Existing Key-pair from AWS server using aws sdk for java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am trying to create EC2 instances on AWS using the aws sdk for java..

here is the runinstance method

```
public static RunInstancesResult createInstaince() {

        RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

        runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-ca381398")
                .withInstanceType("t2.micro")
                .withMinCount(1)
                .withMaxCount(1)
                .withKeyName("java-sdk")
                .withSubnetId("subnet-8eca36f9")
                .withSecurityGroupIds("sg-3f00a25a");

        RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = amazonEC2Client
                .runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

        return runInstancesResult;
    }
```

here i have explicitly specified java-sdk as the key-pair,but now i want the user to be able to choose the key-pair available on the aws server..i saw a function getAMI that gets the AMI from the aws server.can anyone tell me if a function like getKey-pair is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static List<String> getKeyName() {
    DescribeKeyPairsRequest dkpr = new DescribeKeyPairsRequest();
    DescribeKeyPairsResult dkpresult = 
    amazonEC2Client.describeKeyPairs(dkpr);

    List<KeyPairInfo> keyPairs = dkpresult.getKeyPairs();
    List<String> keyPairNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (KeyPairInfo keyPairInfo : keyPairs) {
        keyPairNameList.add(keyPairInfo.getKeyName());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < keyPairs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(keyPairNameList.get(i));
    }

    return keyPairNameList;
}
```

this is the code it will return an arraylist of keynames.

Answer (score 2):

[DescribeKeyPairs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeKeyPairs.html) is what you are looking for. The link is for EC2 API documentation. You may want to look for aws-java sdk method which calls this API.